# how to get live data from REST API using guzzle

Tags: live, broadcast, guzzle, pusher

I'm new to whole live data broadcast. I'm creating a website on **laravel 5.1**, and I need to get live data from a REST API, and after making some changes, broadcast the result to my own users.
I'm using **pusher** to broadcast data to my clients. and I figured, I should use Guzzle and/or CURL to get data from API. but the part I don't understand is how to get live data from API? Is there an option in guzzle that will keep the connection open continuously,or should I create a job to execute guzzle code every few seconds?
I know we use websockets to create a persistent connection between the server and clients to broadcast live data. but how to create a persistent connection between API server and my server to transfer the data?

Thank you friends in advance, appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on an API that you are using. If it's an usual REST API, then there are no options to make a "live" catching. Only pull the API periodically.

You API provider might support webhooks, websockets or some other technologies for push model. Depends on a provider, as I said before.

Comment: thanks Alexey. now when you say "pull the API periodically", what does it mean? like creating a job to get the data every few seconds or there are other (better) ways.As I mentioned before I don't know much about these topics, but executing a job every couple of seconds doesn't seem so good? or maybe it is the way and it doesn't effect server as much as I think.

Comment: Yes, I mean a kind of periodic job to pull the API. Usual HTTP requests. It affects the server, yes, but this is the most general solution. As I said above, your API provider can support push model in some ways (WebSocket, web hooks). Search in the documentation or ask them.